# How add multiple rewritecond htaccess from different file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can i add multiple rewritecond htaccess from different file?
my code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mysite/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ viewpost.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ viewmember.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Dont work : RewriteRule ^(.*)$ viewmember.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only map a URL once.

You have two rules that match the same exact set of URLs (minus the rewrite condition since it only applies to the first rule). The second rule will never trigger.

Make the first rule more restrictive. Maybe something like:

```
RewriteRule ^post/(.*)$ viewpost.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^member/(.*)$ viewmember.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: There can be many reasons. My first guess would be that you have relative paths set for the includes. Change them to absolute paths (start with `/`) or add `<base href="/" />` to the HTML header.